# Vim map not working

Tags: vim

I have written a vim command to help me find method definitions in ruby code.
It takes the word under the cursor and searches for a method definition with that name.

```
:silent execute "normal! /\\v\\s*def (self.)?".expand('<cword>')."\<cr>"
```

It works fine, but now I want to map it to a key command.

```
:nnoremap \m :silent execute "normal! /\\v\\s*def (self.)?".expand('<cword>')."\<cr>"
```

For some reason this isn't working.
When I position the cursor on a method name and type `\m` I get the following error message

```
E114: Missing quote: "\
E15: Invalid expression: "normal! /\\v\\s*def (self.)?".expand('<cword>')."\
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you tried without `\<CR>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `map` itself expands `<cr>`, so the commands it's trying to run are

```
:silent execute "normal! /\\v\\s*def (self.)?".expand('<cword>')."\
"
```

The first line triggers an error because of the unterminated string at the end.

To fix this, try

```
nnoremap <silent> \m :silent execute "normal! /\\v\\s*def (self.)?".expand('<cword>')."\n"<cr>
```

- I've added `<silent>` to make the whole mapping silent (otherwise vim will echo the commands it expands to when running `\m`)
- instead of `\<cr>` you can simply write `\n` in the string, so map will leave it alone
- you need a `<cr>` at the end of the mapping or the command won't run (it'll just sit there waiting for you to press enter)

Answer (score 1):

@melpomene correctly debugged this mapping and pointed out the need to escape `<cr>` in your mapping. You can also use `<lt>` to fix your mapping:

```
nnoremap \m :silent execute 'normal! /\v\s*def (self.)?'.expand('<cword>')."\<lt>cr>"<cr>
```

I have also used single quotes to reduce the escaping in part of the mapping.

However this mapping can be greatly simplified with the use of `<c-r><c-w>` to get the current word under the cursor. This means we can avoid using `:execute`, `:normal`, and `expand()`. Meaning we do not need to do any escaping at all.

```
nnoremap <silent> \m /\v\s*def (self.)?<c-r><c-w><cr>
```

You may want to take this further by using `\zs` to start the match at the word under the cursor instead at the start of the line:

```
nnoremap <silent> \m /\v\s*def (self.)?\zs<c-r><c-w><cr>
```

For more help see:

```
:h <>
:h literal-string
:h c_CTRL-R_CTRL-W
:h /\zs
```